# Comparing RPG to C# and SQL

Tags: c#, sql, ibm-midrange, rpgle

In an RPG program (One of IBM's languages on the AS/400) I can "chain" out to a file to see if a record (say, a certain customer record) exists in the file.  If it does, then I can update that record instantly with new data.  If the record doesn't exist, I can write a new record.  The code would look like this:

```
Customer  Chain CustFile   71 ;turn on indicator 71 if not found
          if    *in71         ;if 71 is "on"
          eval  CustID = Customer;
          eval  CustCredit = 10000;
          write CustRecord
          else                ;71 not on, record found.
          CustCredit = 10000;
          update CustRecord
          endif
```

Not being real familiar with SQL/C#, I'm wondering if there is a way to do a random retrieval from a file (which is what "chain" does in RPG).  Basically I want to see if a record exists.  If it does, update the record with some new information.  If it does not, then I want to write a new record.  I'm sure it's possible, but not quite sure how to go about doing it.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RPG has intrinsic connectivity to the database tables on the system.  That makes it easy to write such succinct operations.

C#, on the other hand, requires you to implement your own database routines (or use a framework like LINQ).

If I was doing this, I would create a class responsible for database manipulation using the System.OLEDB objects.

Some methods might be  (general idea, not actual code):

```
public boolean CheckExists(string TableName, string ColumnName, int ID) {
  //Connect to database
  // Create Command with query  "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM " + TableName.Replace(";","") + " WHERE " + ColumnName.Replace(";","") + " = " + ID 

  Return int.Parse(myQuery.ExecuteScalar) > 0

 //disconnect

}


 public boolean UpdateCredit(int CustID, int newCredit) {
  //Connect to database
  // Create Command with query  "UPDATE CustTable SET CustCredit = " + newCredit.ToString() + " WHERE = CustId = " + CustID 

  myQuery.ExecuteNonQuery

//disconnect

}

public boolean CreateCredit(int CustID, int newCredit) {
  //Connect to database
  // Create Command with query  "INSERT INTO CustTable (CustID, CustCredit) VALUES (" + CustId.ToString + ", " + newCredit.ToString + ")"

  myQuery.ExecuteNonQuery

  //disconnect
}
```

Then your main method world read something like

```
If (CheckExists("CustTable", "CustId", CustID)) {
    UpdateCredit(CustID, 10000)
} else {
    CreateCredit(CustId, 10000)
}
```

Comment: Hmm.  That's pretty good, actually.  I can use that.  Thanks a lot!